# Building GCC-Ada, Syntax error compiling s-excmac.adb with very old gnatmake

Tags: gcc, ada

I'm trying to update our 20-year old Ada compiler, however you need an Ada-compiler to build some parts of GCC+Ada (9.2.0).

The gnatmake is circa 2000, and it's possibly sub-calling GCC 2.8.1.  *Sigh.*

I have already successfully built several Ada parts of GCC, but this `libgnat/` file eludes me:

Compiling `libgnat/s-excmac.adb`:

```
$ gnatmake s-excmac.adb
gcc -c -gnatpg s-excmac.adb
s-excmac.ads:134:44: identifier expected
gnatmake: "s-excmac.adb" compilation error
```

So the problematic line in `s-excmac.ads` is:

```
   type GCC_Exception_Access is access all Unwind_Exception;
   --  Pointer to a GCC exception

   procedure Unwind_DeleteException (Excp : not null GCC_Exception_Access );  -- <-- THIS ONE!

   pragma Import (C, Unwind_DeleteException, "_Unwind_DeleteException");

   --  Procedure to free any GCC exception
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this code.  Is there some turn-of-the-century Ada syntax replacement I can use to get this part of GCC-Ada compiled?

I'm a bit of an Ada NOOB, so please be gentle.

EDIT: Seems like trying to "repair" the `s-excmac.adb` / `s-excmac.ads` is a fool's errand.  The path of lesser resistance is to download a pre-built compiler, and start building the later GCC from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the compiler is older than 2005, compiling the Ada-2005 `not null access` declaration is going to be a problem.

To move forward, you could delete the words "`not null`" and that line will compile and work, but you won't get the desired behaviour (abort with an exception) if you ever pass in a null access type. A better fix would be a wrapper procedure that explicitly checked, and either raised an exception or called the underlying C pro*cough*void function as appropriate.

Additionally, there may be other Ada-2005 features which will also fail to compile, so a better choice would be a compiler upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

Brian is right about the `not null`. But there are likely to be a lot more 2005-isms in the code ...

I believe the maintainers will only guarantee the ability to build a compiler using the previous release, which would imply building GCC 3, using that to build GCC 4, and so on; you might be able to skip a release or two. Long days ahead!

Comment: And going that route, somewhere around gcc 4.7 and higher won't compile without a C++ compiler (in addition to Ada and C)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, building `libgnat` is the latest step. I mean you need to build "new-gcc" using old one, and then with "new-gcc" you will build `libgnat`. In this case you won't get this error.